# multicast: Linux *must not* bind socket to a specific @ but Windows *must*

Tags: linux, windows, binding, multicast

I have a mdns service discovery that uses the following code for initialization

```
void mdnssd_init(struct in_addr host, bool compliant) {
  int sock;
  int res;
  struct ip_mreq mreq;
  struct sockaddr_in addr;
    
  sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
  
  char param = 32;
  setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_TTL, (void*) &param, sizeof(param));
  
  int enable = 1
  setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (void*) &enable, sizeof(enable));
  
  param = 1;
  setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_LOOP, (void*) &param, sizeof(param));

#ifndef _WIN32
  if (compliant) {
    enable = 1;
    setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, (void*)&enable, sizeof(enable));
  } 
#endif

  memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
  addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  /* 
   * Sending *from * 5353 indicates that we do compliant mDNS query. If we chose
   * random ports, the ttl will be much shorter. 
   */
  if (compliant) addr.sin_port = htons(MDNS_PORT);
  // Windows must bind this socket to a specific address, others must not (it's *must*)
#ifdef _WIN32
  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = host.s_addr;
#else
  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
#endif
  socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(addr);
 
  res = bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, addrlen);
  if (res < 0) return;

  // set outgoing interface for multicast (it's optional, INADDR_ANY could be used)
  setsockopt (sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_IF, (void*) &host.s_addr, sizeof(host.s_addr));

  // set multicast groups we are interested by to receive such packets
  memset(&mreq, 0, sizeof(mreq));
  mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr(MDNS_MULTICAST_ADDRESS);
  mreq.imr_interface.s_addr = host.s_addr; // optional, INADDR_ANY can be used
  setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (void*) &mreq, sizeof(mreq));
}
```

It works on all platforms (Linux, Windows, Solaris, FreeBSD, MacOS) but I really don't understand why I need that binding difference between Linux and Windows.

On Linux, if I bind the socket to the address I want to use to send/receive, multicast traffic is *not* received. Note that queries that require unicast response are properly answered. I understand that some settings here are optional and INADDR_ANY can be used, letting the OS select what interface to send request and receive response (and it works).

On the contrary, on Windows, if the socket is *not* bound to a specific address, but set to INADDR_ANY, then no multicast traffic is received. Same, queries requiring unicast responses are received.

So it's very puzzling to me that not both options work. I should be able to bind the socket to the address that will be used for sending/receiving - or not. It should work either way, no?